# Fix box shadow on multi-line span so it doesn't cover the text

Tags: html, css

Here's an example of the issue, I want to know if it's possible for text to go over the shadow from the line below.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 > span {
  background-color: #D32;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    0 0 0 7px #D32;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2><span>A HEADLINE WITH BACKGROUND-COLOR PLUS BOX-SHADOW :3</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an extra span that you make `position: relative`

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 > span {
  background-color: #D32;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    0 0 0 7px #D32;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
h2 > span > span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2><span><span>A HEADLINE WITH BACKGROUND-COLOR PLUS BOX-SHADOW :3</span></span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: No chance for a CSS only solution?